# How to replace portion of a vector using Rust?

Tags: vector, rust

## What is the best way to replace a specific portion of a vector with a new vector?

As of now, I am using hardcoded code to replace the vector. What is the most effective way to achieve this?

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut v = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
    
    let u = vec![0,0,0,0];

    v[2] = u[0];
    v[3] = u[1];
    v[4] = u[2];
    v[5] = u[3];
    

    println!("v = {:?}", v);
}
```

[Permalink to the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=aa12319863bf39fe0241a73a2fabe0ce)

Is there any function to replace the vector with given indices?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For `Copy` types:

```rust
v[2..][..u.len()].copy_from_slice(&u);
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=fcfaa2768b2c50e7015e4a7d6002c638).

For non-`Copy` types:

```rust
v.splice(2..2 + u.len(), u);
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=709d64cc638489649bf0a0bbc82356f1).

Comment: For the non-`Copy` scenario, you can also use `clone_from_slice` - not sure if there's any benefit to that over `splice` though.

Comment: @JoeClay It _may_ be faster, but it needs to clone the elements so it will be a behavior change and also likely slower.

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

```
let offset : usize = 2;
u.iter().enumerate().for_each(|(index, &val)| {
   v[index + offset] = val;
});
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c8d2fdabe026de9d9016be1fbbdd5b4c)